# how to unload data with BCP?

Tags: sql

How to generate BCP command lines from DbArtisan or Sql Server Management Studio ?
I have been struggling for 2 hours to just get data out of a table via my windows shell, whatever I do, all it tells me is "Requested server name not found", altough the server itself and the instance of Sql Server are "pingable"...

Comment: Have you tried `BULK INSERT` instead?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: yeah well that obviously does not help with my current issue. Cf question title.

Comment: I am able to perform a bcp out from DbArtisan. I'd like the command line that it uses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally opted for using SSMS tools. It is a free add-in for SQL server Management Studio. One feature I am using is the ability to generate insert statements for a bunch a tables in just one click... That is also interesting for me considering that I am using log shipping and these insert statements will be captured contrarily to BCP actions.